# Key and Foreign Key Relations

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

**Table 1** I have a table housing all of my dealers and roadshows.  I am attempting to add the ability to add an event at these locations.  This table has `location_id`.

To do this I created another table.

**Table 2** In this new table I have an id, and an `event_location_id`.

Which way do I make the relationship?

I want to be able to daisy chain from Table1.Table2.count() in asp.net MVC.

In which table do I make the foreign key relationship?

Comment: What is the relationship between event and location?

Comment: Table 1 location_id can have 0 or one or many events attached to each dealer/roadshow. @RufusL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `location_id` is the primary key of **Table 1** you would want to add a foreign key to **Table 2** on the `event_location_id` that references `location_id` of **Table 1**.

Having said that, a table that houses dealers *and* roadshows doesn't sound like it's been designed correctly. It seems like it would make more sense to have a dealers table, a roadshows table, a relationship between them, and events that hang off of one or the other.

Comment: I think it is the other way around.  Event_Location_Id is the pk and Location_Id would be the FK in table 1

Comment: Thank you.  I was doing it backwards going from Table 1 to Table 2.    I went from Table 2 to Table 1 and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

In a one-to-many relationship, the primary key is held in the 'one' table, and the foreign key is held in the 'many' table. So if a location can have many events, you would have a column in the `Event` table called `LocationId` which would map to the `location_id` primary key of the `Location` table.